# How to implement instant welcome message for Skype bot?

Tags: botframework, skype, skypedeveloper

Is there any way to implement welcome message for Skype bot? 
For example:

1. User adds Skype bot to his contacts list
2. Bot instantly writes a message "Hello User, nice to meet you!"

My bot is deployed in Azure using Azure Bot Service and I'm using latest Node.js botbuilder SDK

Is there any "Added to contacts webhook"?

Comment: use `ContactRelationUpdate` event

Answer (score 0):

ContactRelationUpdate event works